# Adding link to featherlight.js pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, featherlight.js

A pop-up appears when someone visit my website. I've used featherlight.js. i've added link to pop-up in HTML and when i click it, it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with featherlight.js

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="lightbox" id="lightbox">
    <p>Hello: <img align="right" src="img/IE-flag.gif"></p>
    <br>
    <p>Register now to qualify.</p>
    <br>
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
    <br>
    <center><p style="font-size:10px">No thanks</p>
    <script src="js/featherlight.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.featherlight('#lightbox', {
            closeOnClick: 'anywhere'
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `closeOnClick: 'anywhere'`, you're telling Featherlight to intercept clicks everywhere, including in the dialog and close the dialog...

Remove that option and you'll be ok.

Comment: Yes it's working. Is there a possibility , that except for that button , it gets closed every time i click on anywhere. Is there a way to add exception for that button ?